# Updating order status every 30 seconds

Tags: java, android

I am working on Track order screen. After User placing an order, Admin makes changes in order status to **Accepted** from **Pending**. I would like to display order status in real time on Track Order Screen. Whenever admin changes at the back-end, the status should be changed.

Here is the Initial Screen on Clicking Track Order Button. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx1s9.jpg

When User Selects drop-down, all orders based on the user will be displayed. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS5Y7.jpg

Here is the track order screen after selecting particular order
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOPnq.jpg. As per the image, once at the back-end changed it to out for delivery, in real time I want to point the bar to order out for delivery.

Here is my Track order Activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try
    {
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_track_order, container, false);
    try
    {
        mView = view;

        getOrders(); // It gives me all the orders on clicking spinner

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        GSLogger.e(ex);
        showToast(getString(R.string.error_loading_fragments));
    }

    return view;

}


private void init_AppContents(final ArrayList<TrackOrderModel> ordersList)
{
    try
    {

        final ArrayList<String> order_arr = new ArrayList<>();
        for(TrackOrderModel trackOrderModel : ordersList)
        {
            order_arr.add(trackOrderModel.getRestaurant_name()+"  "+trackOrderModel.getData_time());
        }

        final SpinnerAdapter area_arrayAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, order_arr);
        order_spinner.setAdapter(area_arrayAdapter);
        order_spinner.setSelection(0);

        order_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
            {
                order_id = ordersList.get(position).getOrder_id();
                tran_id = ordersList.get(position).getOrder_id();


                if(!order_id.equals("0"))

                    getOrderStatus(order_id); // Based on the order id, it displays particular order status. Here I want it to change every 30 seconds.
                else
                {
                    order_received_circle.setImageResource(R.mipmap.circle_grey);

                    order_ready_progress.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.light_grey_2));
                    order_ready_circle.setImageResource(R.mipmap.circle_grey);

                    order_deliver_progress.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.light_grey_2));
                    order_deliver_circle.setImageResource(R.mipmap.circle_grey);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        GSLogger.e(ex);
        showToast(getString(R.string.error_init_content));
    }
}
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: why don't you ask for a silent notification from web end whenever Admin make changes in order status to Accepted from Pending , on receiving notification use local broadcast to refresh your list.

Comment: what solution are you currently using ?

Comment: @UmarHussain I am new to android. If you could give me any solution, that would be fine. I am thinking of timer task. I dont know where to put

Comment: @MohdSaquib Can you give me any link so that i can refer?

Comment: you can setup firebase notification setup over admin  and mobile app, after notification receive just pass a broadcast through your firebaseNotificationSerivce to trackorderscreen.
here is the link
https://console.firebase.google.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Broadcast receiver to check order status and show to a notification to user when order status change, Another way is to use a Runnable thread or Timer() to send a request and check order status every 30 seconds

Comment: Using a timer to check every 30 seconds is a poor solution to be honest. If you already have the ability to work in the backend too, then build in a notification for the app. Others explained how with firebase. An `Event triggered`refresh is better design and is better for the performance. No need to utilize an additional thread and keep the device busy. 
If you however want to use the timer version I would moreover recommend using something like `Quartz` which is basically a programmable Cronjob.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Firebase Cloud Messaging, polling the server for the results using the timer is not a good way as it not power efficient way. 
With FCM you would be able to receive notification (which you can use for both actual user notification or just receiving the payload) when the backend server updates the data and fire a notification about data. 
This is a efficient way as its managed by Google with better implementation

Read this documentation.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Will go through it.